# How to render taxonomy field_custom in page--taxonomy--term.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom field in my taxonomy. How to render programmatically this taxonomy field in page--taxonomy--term.twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare the Twig variable in a preprocess hook:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    $term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term');
    $variables['field_example'] = $term->field_example->view();
  }
}
```